# Why does Delete method of Amazon DynamoDB not return deleted result?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating an express api for **delete operation**, after successful deletion of item, i want that deleted item to be shown as response, the item is getting deleted from the table but the API gives **empty object {}** as response when ran from CURL command, i am following these [docs from aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.06).

here is my code

```
router.delete('/delete/:id',function(req, res, next) {
  
  const params = {
    TableName: 'Notes',
    Key: {
      id: req.params.id,
    },
  };

  dynamoDb.delete(params, function (error,data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Could not update user' });
    }
    res.status(200).json(data);
  });
})
```

curl command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X DELETE xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/dev/user/delete/alexdebrie2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DynamoDB [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html) of the `DeleteItem` operation clearly explains that:

> In addition to deleting an item, you can also return the item's attribute values in the same operation, using the `ReturnValues` parameter.

So a delete operation does not, by default, return the old value of the deleted item. If you want that, you need to pass the `ReturnValues` option to the DynamoDB request. I'm not familiar with whatever programming language you're using to implement this, but I hope you can figure this out for yourself.

Comment: deleteItem doesnt not exist anymore :) please check docs for nodejs delete operation on aws, this doesn't solve me issue, if you readmy code in my callback there is data argument to log data returned from dynamodb

Comment: DeleteItem still exists on the DynamoDB API - you'd need to figure out how it's mapped to the particular library that you are using

Comment: @peter please check these docs, this is the recommended way from AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.06, my delete operation works but data is not being returned !!!!

Comment: I don't know anything about node.js but I refuse to believe that Amazon hid one of their features - which I used byself in both Python and Java SDKs - in the node.js SDK. The following link suggests that a "deleteItem" function still exists: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#deleteItem-property

Comment: I just realized that my link was from the Javascript SDK v2, and there is now a v3... I'll look further...

Comment: v3 also seems to support DeleteItem and its ReturnValues option: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/codegen/sdk-codegen/aws-models/dynamodb.2012-08-10.json - but I don't know through which syntax. I never used the JS SDK myself.

Comment: Here is one possible syntax for the DeleteItem command in the Javascript SDK v3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/deleteitemcommand.html

Comment: `deleteItem()` does still exist.  It's just on class `DynamoDB` itself, and delegated to by `DocumentClient.delete()`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#delete-property

Comment: So OP could just supply the same parameters - in this case `ReturnValues` - to `delete()` and they will be passed through to `deleteItem()`.

Comment: this worked `In addition to deleting an item, you can also return the item's attribute values in the same operation, using the ReturnValues parameter.` https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/803

Answer (score 1):

```
let params = {
    TableName: tablename,
    Key: {
      hashKey: ,`enter code here`,
      id: `enter code here`
    },
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(hashKey)",// checks if item exists
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_OLD'
  };
  dynamoDB.delete(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: error.statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify(error),
      });
      return;
    }
    else {
      console.log(result);
    }
    // create a response
    const response = {
      isBase64Encoded: false,
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(result),
    };
    console.log(response);
    callback(null, response);
  });
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.